# Can an app handle a admin and user levels?

Tags: android

I'm creating a offline viewing app about herbal medicine. I'm a bit bothered on how to update my herbal every time there is newly approved herbal without coding it directly. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Add permission levels to your logged in users.

Comment: Title says one thing, description says another.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to find some sort of list of herbal medicines that updates whenever a new one is approved, then add that to a list that is checked whenever that app is connected to the internet. You could also make it open-source, but that can get messy.